# Minimizing a chunk of list variables within python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a chunk of list variables down below. Is there a way I could assign a bunch of variable names as list all at once? With a for loop or such? I am open to any ideas :).

```
#Keeping track of the General Long and Short Compounding,General Long and Short Non Compounding Values
Amount_list=[]
S_Amount_list= []
L_Amount_list= []
Non_compounding_list = []
S_Non_compounding_list = []
L_Non_compounding_list = []

#Positions
#scatter graph variables
LongPosition = []
LongPosition_x = []
ShortPosition = []
ShortPosition_x = []
```

Comment: The length of what exactly?

Comment: I should replace the word length with repetition, just updated the info

Comment: still not clear!

Comment: You could do a lot of things, however you should think about readability and maintainability. Having the lists defined like you already have is a lot clearer than any sort of dict or loop IMO, coming across a dict with no idea what the keys are makes for some of the worst code to maintain

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid declaring a bunch of lists individually, you can always use `defaultdict` as a factory of empty lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_my_lists = defaultdict(list)
```

Now you effectively have all the empty lists you could ever want.  You can access them by name and do anything you would do to an empty list:

```
all_my_lists['Amount'].append(amount)
```

Once the list is created, it persists; `defaultdict` just creates an empty list for you the first time you use any given key.

The problem with this approach is that if you have a typo in one of those keys, it's very easy to miss and it will produce non-obvious bugs.  Named variables are harder to mess up because if you typo one it'll probably lead to an obvious runtime error (and if you use a typechecker, it'll error even before you run your program).

If you have a large number of lists in the same scope, though, what that *probably* means is that you're not modeling your data in the best way.  Maybe some of those pieces of data should be in a list of lists, or a dictionary, or a class of object that manages related chunks of data.  It's unfortunately impossible to give recommendations on how to improve your data model without knowing more about the rest of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using dictionaries? Something like

```py
#Keeping track of the General Long and Short Compounding,General Long and Short Non Compounding Values
lists = {
    'Amount': []],
    'S_Amount': [],
    'L_Amount': [],
    'Non_compounding': [],
    'S_Non_compounding': [],
    'L_Non_compounding': []
{

#Positions
#scatter graph variables
positions = {
    'LongPosition': [],
    'LongPosition_x': [],
    'ShortPosition': [],
    'ShortPosition_x': []
}
```

You can then access the values with something like

```py
amount = lists['Amount']
```